# ¿Como puedo validar un input en un box de una web desde la consola del navegador con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un snippet para automatizar la entrada de datos en una web, me pide que introduzca un monto, he probado de dos maneras

```js
document.getElementById("pricePerUnit").setAttribute('value','0.13');
```

```js
document.getElementById("pricePerUnit").value = "0.13" ;
```

y solo en la funcion setAttribute se modifica el valor pero no me deja apretar el boton de submit, como si faltara algun tipo de validacion, ¿como puedo introducir el precio y validar por comando?

Aqui querria introducir el valor en value:

```html
<input aria-invalid="false" id="pricePerUnit" name="pricePerUnit" placeholder="Amount" value="" style="cursor: text;">
```

Comment: Tengo unas dudas, 1 - El botón tiene activa la propiedad `disabled` o algo parecido? 2 - Qué debería pasar al poner el `value` en el `input`? 3 - Qué debes "validar por comando"?

Comment: @DjCrazy  La casilla del monto esta vacia y el boton de submit esta desactivado, quiero introducir por consola de comandos un monto, y en ese momento me deberia dejar pulsar el boton, como que ya hay un valor agregado,  pero el boton sigue desactivado como si aun no introduje el valor, por eso pregunto si existe algun comando para validar la entrada de datos... ya sea poner valor true a algo ...check validation etc

Comment: si en vez de hacerlo por comando hago click y pongo los numeros por teclado automaticamente me sale el boton de submit, pero al introducir el value por comando no me deja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo debes agregar una validación, si hay datos, activas el botón pasándole la propiedad `disabled` en `true`.

```js
let precio = document.getElementById("pricePerUnit");
let boton = document.getElementById("btnHacerAlgo");
//Asignar el valor al input
precio.setAttribute('value','0.13');
//Validar si el value tiene datos...
if(precio.value != ''){
  //Activar el botón
  boton.disabled = false;
} else {
  boton.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input aria-invalid="false" id="pricePerUnit" name="pricePerUnit" placeholder="Amount" value="" style="cursor: text;">
<button id="btnHacerAlgo" disabled>Hacer algo</button>
```

O incluso podría ser más simple:

```js
document.getElementById("pricePerUnit").setAttribute('value','0.13');
document.getElementById("btnHacerAlgo").disabled = false;
```

```html
<input aria-invalid="false" id="pricePerUnit" name="pricePerUnit" placeholder="Amount" value="" style="cursor: text;">
<button id="btnHacerAlgo" disabled>Hacer algo</button>
```